# replacing all instances of %X with Xth argument in args in python

Tags: python, replace, isinstance

I am currently trying to replace the occurrence of a number x with the xth argument in a string. Here is my code:

```
def simple_format(format, *args):
    res = format.replace("%", "")
    for x in res:
        if (isinstance(x, int)):
            res = res.replace(x, args(x))
     return res
```

The first replace is used to remove the occurrence of `%` in the string and the next is to check if the variable encountered is a number and if it is, replacing it with the argument.

For example, 
    `simple_format("hello %0", "world", "Ben")` should return `"hello world"`.The desired output is not achieved. What is the mistake? Is there any way to do it using replace method?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think in your example 0 is seen as a str and not a int, you should verify if x belongs to [0-9] then cast it to int

Comment: Will check it.Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more basic approach IMO, and probably more readable:

```
import re

s = 'hello %0, how %2 do you come to %1?'

replacements = ['world','stack overflow','often']

for match in re.findall(r'\%[0-9]+', s):
    s = re.sub(match, replacements[int(re.sub(r'\%','',match))], s)
```

Output:

```
'hello world, how often do you come to stack overflow?'
```

Explanation:

`re.findall(r'\%[0-9]+', s)` finds all `%0`, `%2`, `%1`, etc. in the string `s`

For each of those matches, use `re.sub()` to substitute in the corresponding string from `replacements`. Iterate through all matches to be replaced.

Comment: Thank you!! But can't it be done using replace method?

Comment: If you were simply replacing the `%` symbols and nothing else, then sure. However, it sounds from your OP that you are interested in having your replacement dependent on the `int` following the `%` symbol. In which case, it's more advantageous to use `re.sub()` to specify the pattern you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

Your current approach is bugged, as `x` will always be type `str`, so the `isinstance` check will always be False. Plus, even if you fixed that, your code will replace every *single* digit to its index in `args` (as long as you also change `args(x)` to `args[x]`).

I would use a regex substitution to convert your string to a proper format literal. Then you can use string format to insert the arguments.

```
import re
def simple_format(format, *args):
    new = re.sub(r"%(\d+)", r"{\1}", format)
    return new.format(*args)

print(simple_format("hello %0", "world", "Ben"))
# hello world
```

Comment: Isn't the intent to write her own version of format, not fall back to the built in method?

Comment: Thank you!! But I am beginner. So it would be better, if I do it without any complicated stuff. Is there any other way, other than using regex

Comment: @dashiell I don't see the OP mentioning about that